# Read file by line then process as different variable

Tags: bash

I have created a text file with a list of file names like below

```
022694-39.tar
022694-39.tar.2017-05-30_13:56:33.OLD
022694-39.tar.2017-07-04_09:22:04.OLD
022739-06.tar
022867-28.tar
022867-28.tar.2018-07-18_11:59:19.OLD
022932-33.tar
```

I am trying to read the file line by line then strip anything after *.tar* with awk and use this to create a folder unless it exists.

Then the plan is to copy the original file to the new folder with the original full name stored in $LINE.

```
$QNAP= "Path to storage"
$LOG_DIR/$NOVA_TAR_LIST= "Path to text file containing file names"
```

```
while read -r LINE; do
    CURNT_JOB_STRIPED="$LINE | `awk -F ".tar" '{print $1}'`"
    if [ ! -d "$QNAP/$CURNT_JOB_STRIPED" ]
        then
        echo "Folder $QNAP/$CURNT_JOB_STRIPED doesn't exist."
        #mkdir "$QNAP/$CURNT_JOB_STRIPED"
    fi
done <"$LOG_DIR/$NOVA_TAR_LIST"
```

Unfortunately this seems to be trying to join all the file names together when trying to create the directories rather than doing them one by one and I get a 
`File name too long`

output:

```
......951267-21\n951267-21\n961075-07\n961148-13\n961520-20\n971333-21\n981325-22\n981325-22\n981743-40\n999111-99\n999999-04g\n999999-44': File name too long
```

Apologies if this is trivial, bit of a rookie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your script as follows:

```
CURNT_JOB_STRIPED=$(echo "${LINE}" | awk -F ".tar" '{print $1}')
```

You have to use `$(...)` for command substitution. Also, you should print the variable `LINE` in order to prevent the shell from interpreting its value as a command but passing it to the next command of the pipe (as an input) instead. Finally, you should remove the backticks from the `awk` expression (this is the deprecated syntax for command substitution) since what you want is the result from the piping commands.

For further information, take a look over http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Alternatively, and far less readable (neither with a higher performance, thus just as a "curiosity"), you can just use instead of the whole while loop:

```
xargs -I{} bash -c 'mkdir -p "${2}/${1%.tar*}"' - '{}' "${QNAP}" < "${LOG_DIR}/${NOVA_TAR_LIST}"
```

Comment: Hi danlor thanks for the solution and additional info.... i think i will skip the xargs one though, as you said far less readable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `` CURNT_JOB_STRIPED="$LINE | `awk -F ".tar" '{print $1}'`" `` line.

The `` `command` `` is legacy a syntax, `$(command)` should be used instead.

`$LINE` variable should be printed so awk can receive its value trough a pipe.

If you run the whole thing in a sub shell ( `$(command)` ) you can assign the output into a variable: `var=$(date)`

Is is safer to put variables into `${}` so if there is surrounding text you will not get unexpected results.

This should work:
`CURNT_JOB_STRIPED=$(echo "${LINE}" | awk -F '.tar' '{print $1}')`

---

With variable substitution this can be achieved with more efficient code, and it also clean to read I believe.

Variable substitution is not change the `${LINE}` variable so it can be used later as the variable that have the full filename unchanged while `${LINE%.tar*}` cut the last `.tar` text from the variable value and with `*` anything after that.

```
while read -r LINE; do
        if [ ! -d "${QNAP}/${LINE%.tar*}" ]
        then
                echo "Folder ${QNAP}/${LINE%.tar*} doesn't exist."
                #mkdir "${QNAP}/${LINE%.tar*}"
        fi
done <"${LOG_DIR}/${NOVA_TAR_LIST}"
```

This way you not store the directory name as variable and `${LINE}` only store the filename. If You need it into a variable you can do that easily: `var="${LINE%.tar*}"`

---

Variable Substitution:

There is more i only picked this 4 for now as they similar and relevant here.

${var#pattern} - Use value of var after removing text that match pattern from the left

${var##pattern} - Same as above but remove the longest matching piece instead the shortest

${var%pattern} - Use value of var after removing text that match pattern from the right

${var%%pattern} - Same as above but remove the longest matching piece instead the shortest

Comment: Note that all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell and POSIX-specified utilities; application-defined names should have at least one lowercase character. See fourth paragraph of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html for the relevant specification.

Comment: (I don't, personally, tend to agree that `"${foo}"` is any safer than `"$foo"` except in clearly-identifiable circumstances -- `$foo_suffix` is a very clear and explicit case -- but... folks' style views differ; to-may-toe, to-mah-toe. OTOH, I recently spotted a security bug caused by the typo `$foo}` causing a test to operate against the wrong filename, so arguably, increasing the amount of syntax used increases the number of potential mistakes).

Comment: ...the above nitpicks notwithstanding, this answer has very good advice overall; welcome to the site!

Comment: ...oh, you might consider `<<<"$LINE"` instead of `echo "$LINE" |`, as well; counterintuitive as it may seem, setting up a tempfile for a heredoc is often faster than forking a subshell to handle the write end of a pipeline. See the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes I missed to mention var names with capital letters are something that we should avoid as well. I thought about mention `<<<` operator but I had to work older systems where that not exist, so I decided to avoid to do so, to keep code more portable.